# Issues with non-inverting op-amp Pspice sim

Tags: operational-amplifier, pspice, non-inverting

I want to build the circuit pictured here in Figure 1: [image]

When I simulate it, this is the result:

[image]

For some reason, the output of the op-amp is always 183.8mV and if I work backwards using the expression for the op-amp output, I don't get the correct value for Vshunt.

Here's what I've tried:

1. Making a dedicated 22V voltage source for the op-amp since, according to the datasheet, the max supply voltage is +/- 22V.
2. Changing the Rshunt value, RL value, Rf, and Rg values to see if it affects the value of Vo and nothing seems to change it.

What am I messing up here?

Comment: Someone really needs to make a canonical "Why does my LM741 circuit not work right?" question.

Comment: You could be that someone :) I've simulated with this LM741 part before without issue, but for some reason I'm having problems here.

Comment: Short answer: Power the op amp with +24V/-2V. I'll let someone else come pick the low lying fruit.

Comment: Yeah I want a single-supply op-amp so I don't know how I could make the -2V work.